# Scrapy: re-crawling with the same rule

Tags: python, scrapy

i am using scrapy to extract reviews from tripAdvisor.

my start_urls are the hotels. for example:

```
http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60763-d80075-Reviews-Amsterdam_Court_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html#REVIEWS.
```

from this pages i am crawling to the reviews page, using this rules:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("ShowUserReviews-g.*",), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="REVIEWS"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a',), unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow= True),

    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("ShowUserReviews-g.*",),restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="REVIEWS"]/div[contains(@class,"deckTools btm")]',),unique=True),callback='parse_item',follow=True),
)
```

an example for reviews page:

```
http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187514-d228523-r275442835-Hotel_Petit_Palace_Arturo_Soria-Madrid.html#REVIEWS
```

at the end of every reviews page there are links for the next reviews pages for this hotel, numbered like : 1, 2, 3, 4 ..... i can use the same rule i think, the next addresses are similar.

follow this printscreen:

```
http://s16.postimg.org/w68m82ouc/Screenshot_from_2015_07_02_12_36_03.jpg
```

my questions:

1. how the rule crawling works? the scraper can re-crawling to the next reviews pages with the same rule? i need something else?
2. how can i avoid crawling to reviews pages i saw before?
   for example, crawl from page no.3 to page no.1 and 2..?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter for the "Next" site in the Rule for the next sites. This avoids visiting already visited review-sites.

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("ShowUserReviews-g.*",), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="REVIEWS"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a[text() = "Next"]',), unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow= True)
```

Comment: Thanks. if i will add this rule to the old rules, it will work? the scraper will re-crawl to the next pages? add it as the first rule? im asking because i read about problems with more than one rule. how can i know the order these rules are been checked?

Comment: Most of the time I have two rules for such sites: one is for the navigation URLs, the other for the detail sites. The order does not matter -- or at least I never found it that way. So I would change the first rule of your scraper to this and Scrapy should happily go for the next pages as long as they are available -- and parse the bodies of the sites.